# Change of Variables of Reaction-Diffusion Equation into Heat Equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am seeking the explicit formula for the solution of 
$u_t-\Delta u=cu=f$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ x $(0,T)$ with initial condition $u(\dot{},0)=g$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

If I let $v(x,t)=e^{-ct}u(x,t)$ and multiply the PDE through by $e^{-ct}$ I get $d_{t}v=u(x,t)e^{-ct}-ce^{-ct}u(x,t)=e^{-ct}\Delta u+e^{-ct}f= \Delta v + e^{-ct}f$.  Thus we are left with $d_{t}v-\Delta v= e^{-ct}f$, which is essentially the non homogeneous heat equation with forcing function $ e^{-ct}f$.

Assuming this is the correct change of variables, how do I go about solving this equation.  I know the traditional homogeneous equation is solved using separation of variables.  I'm just kind of confused how I solve for an explicit solution given the single initial condition I am given.  Can I just use the convolution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the fundamental solution of the heat equation and the the forcing function $e^{-ct}f$?

Comment: Could you tell me a reference for this equation?

Answer (score 0):

Check formula (2) here: http://math.tut.fi/~piche/pde/notes05.pdf or google "Duhamel's principle"